# Is it possible to make an Xcode app to log into iCloud

Tags: ios, icloud

I know how to implement iCloud on an iOS app but the problem is that it would use your personal iCloud account that is logged in into your settings. My question is that can I make an app to manually log in into a different iCloud account every time the user launches the app? Similar to apps like Find my iPhone where it would always ask for your Apple ID.

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done. An iOS app only has access to whatever iCloud account is logged in at the device level, if any. There is no way to let the user choose or log into a different account just for the app.